# audio play in background issue

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, ionic-framework, media

I'm developing an application in ionic using cordova-plugin-media and cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation. When I try to play an audio in background it throws the error code 4 (MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED). This works perfectly in Android and iPhone 5s but fails in some iOS devices (iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s).

Any idea about how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and it was because I was using an OGG file. Android supports OGG but iOS does not. Wikipedia has a good table showing which browsers support which audio types (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_coding_format). Android is the same as Chrome, and iOS matches Safari.

The solution is to use MP3 or WAV files. I recommend MP3 since you get much smaller file sizes.